# What does <a href=“?var=something “></a>

Tags: html, href

What does `<a href="?var=something"></a>`
In above tag what `?` Does

I studying one web frame work and there it was mentioned during pagination topic.when we click on that link I can url followed by `?var=somevalue` without slash in between

Answer (score 3):

`?` indicates the start query string on the URL. Since it is at the start of the `href` value, it would go to the same route but with the new query string values.

Comment: Thanks , could you provide some doc to know more about this

Comment: If we mention link followed by ? And variables, it will go to the link with those variables after ? , but if we ? Followed by variables like I mention in my question, does this call the same page with given variables?

Comment: @user3146100 yea that’s what I mean by route

Comment: Thanks you so much Daniel